# How to Post on Google Plus with Google plus api by Activities.insert in Asp.net Server or Client Side

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin, google-apis-explorer

Guys i want to Post on Google Plus  with **Google plus api** by **Activities.insert** in Server Side on Asp.net C# .
i am done sign in process and i have also access-token then i try lots of code.but not successful .Please help him to short out this Problem

Comment: "i try lots of code" - where's that code?

Comment: The Google+ api does not have a method called Activites Insert.  https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities .   The Google plus domains api has a method called activities insert.  which will insert to your domains account google+ and only users who have installed your application will be able to see it https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert   Make sure that you have granted your service account access to your Google+ domains account via the admin page.

Comment: To add the Google+ Domains API is only available for paid G Suite clients.